# Why did the builders put eletrical trimbox on top of the siding?

Tags: electrical, trim, siding

[image: trim block on siding]

This one was on my punch list for closing. The field manager couldn't explain why there was trim box on top of siding. The inspector that I hired told me that this wasn't the standard... Is this the industry standard or pure laziness?

Also, how hard is to replace a fiber cement board? They wouldn't fix this "cosmetic issue"
[image]

Comment: I have a hunch about the electrical, but it depends on the age of the house, so when was it built? As far as the siding, I would agree that those defects are cosmetic. I certainly wouldn't replace the boards for that - but better prep before painting would take care of it - basically either sand down if it is high or fill if it is low.

Comment: It's a brand new build... I am trying to close it on Thursday since my rate lock expires on same day.

Comment: Yep, make sure they leave you with a can of paint, or at least the "make and model" of what they used.  The double trim ring on brand new construction, with both trim rings on the *outside* of the siding certainly looks halfass.  Especially when the trim rings appear to be different colors.

Comment: If these are the worst problems, call it done. My hunch, which is 100% wrong, is that the outdoor receptacle was originally flush with the siding and at a later time was upgraded to a modern weather-resistant/in-use-cover/GFCI. The catch being that often older (1960s or earlier) boxes are not large enough for a GFCI/receptacle. The easy solution then is to put on some sort of extension and box. But that isn't the case with a new build.

Comment: I fully understand their reluctance to fix the cosmetic issue (which is all it really is) on the siding. They're not going to replace it - they'd need to bring in two different subcontractors (siding and painting) and it would be ridiculous. But they *could* have a handyman on staff who would sand/touch-up. End result - you'll be that handyman. But as Huesmann pointed out, if they can leave you with paint and/or paint specs that would help a lot.

Comment: It kinda blows my mind because they replaced everything I've bluetaped last week except the "popped" siding. There were several chipped sidings. I'll ask them tomorrow what's going on under the siding as well. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: It sucks to have deficiencies. If I was in your shoes, I’d weigh the hassle of chasing them vs the hassle of a couple of hours of diy.

Comment: Yeah it's probably going to be a DIY thing. I am going to ask them if they can provide me the paint and siding if the labor is the issue here.